# Call to acquireToken fails with "Set-Cookie header is ignored in response from url... Cookie length should be less than or equal to 4096 characters

Tags: adal

In my code I successfully call authenticationContext.login() to authenticate the user. A few lines later I call authenticationContext.acquireToken(...). The call to acquireToken fails with the message "Set-Cookie header is ignored in response from url... Cookie length should be less than or equal to 4096 characters"

Two requests are performed, one to get the id_token and the other to get an access_token, in both cases the http response contains a series of Set-Cookie headers:

- Set-Cookie: AADSSO=; expires=somedate; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
- Set-Cookie: ESTSAUTHPERSISTENT=<**760 chars**>; domain=somedomain; expires=somedate; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
- Set-Cookie: ESTSAUTH=<**160 chars**>; domain=somedomain; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
- Set-Cookie: ESTSAUTHLIGHT=<**37 chars**>; path=/; secure
- Set-Cookie: ESTSSC=00; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
- Set-Cookie: buid=<**206 chars**>; expires=somedate GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
- Set-Cookie: x-ms-sts-inner=1; expires=somedate; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
- Set-Cookie: SignInStateCookie=<**2000 chars**>; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
- Set-Cookie: SignInStateCookie1=<**1220 chars**>; domain=.somedomain; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
- Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfirst; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
- Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=estsfirst; path=/; secure; HttpOnly

The second request fails, presumably due to the large amount of cookies already present from the first call.

How can I fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like the issue was with my browser, clearing all cookies (not only those from localhost) solved the issue